# Are there countries that have drastically reduced regulations on childcare in order to make it more affordable?

Tags: education, regulation

Pretty much every developed country struggles with high costs on childcare. But only 3 approaches that I think can reduce the (visible) cost to parents:

1. Invite more foreign workers from countries with low wages
2. Increase subsidies
3. Reduce regulations

Are there any developed countries that have decided to try approach #3 and drastically reduced their regulations on childcare provision? And did they see a corresponding decrease in prices?

Comment: Unless by "reduce regulation" you mean "allow any number of children to be 'cared for' by any number of adults", which tends towards "lock as many children in a room as fit"

Comment: @Caleth yes, though that's not the only regulation resulting in higher prices. But parents have much more skin in the game than bureaucrats so they're excellent judges of what provider ratios are appropriate.

Comment: I do not see how the [education] tag applies to this question. Perhaps, [social-policy] is a better tag.

Comment: Child care is almost completely unregulated in many, if not most countries, even fairly developed ones.

Comment: @ohwilleke yep and it's correspondigly cheap in places which don't have regulatory burdens

Comment: @JonathanReez Childcare is cheap in absolute terms in poor countries where average salaries are low, so it is not actually cheap for the people who live there. It is expensive in developed countries where salaries are high, even for unqualified labor. Can you point to a single example of a rich country where legal child care is cheap?

Comment: @quarague childcare is about 2x cheaper in France than in the UK, thanks to allowing a larger ratio of providers to children. It obviously cannot be cheaper than the cost of labor but it can reach much lower levels without regulation.

Comment: The [UK government](https://www.gov.uk/government/consultations/childcare-regulatory-changes) has changed the permitted ratios of staff to children, but I don't know if changing from 1:4 to 1:5 (along with other minor changes) could be called drastic.

Comment: `Invite more foreign workers from countries with low wages` - This isn't going to change how much you have to pay in the country the children are in.  Things like minimum wage laws aren't dependent on country of origin.  How much labor costs is primarily dependent on how difficult it is to find un-tapped labor that meets whatever criteria.  This doesn't (necessarily) depend on regulation - if there's a surplus of labor meeting even a mandated requirement, that can still depress wages.

Comment: `And did they see a corresponding decrease in prices?` - There's a potentially faulty premise here; deregulation doesn't directly decrease _prices for the consumer_, but instead decreases _costs for the business_.  Whether any cost reduction is reflected by a price reduction can be complicated.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse both economics 101 and hundreds of years of history point to a reduction of costs always resulting in a reduction of prices.

Comment: @JonathanReez - That's not a _direct_ effect, though, but usually rather a function of (potentially theoretical) competition.  This is why things like natural monopolies can be so problematic, because even with effectively zero cost it can still be impossible to generate competitors and lower prices.  True, childcare doesn't fall into such a case, but even with reduced/zero regulations it's potentially possible to fall into similar situations in the edge cases (eg, the population of a city increasing so fast there are no available buildings to use).

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer as I'm on the move atm, and this is just one example, but had a recent discussion on this subject:

https://english.ey.gov.tw/News3/9E5540D592A5FECD/7b033800-d295-4a7a-8fba-dfbf617142d6

Taiwan:

> National child care policy for ages 0-6
>
> To alleviate the national security issue posed by the declining birth rate, the government is expanding fertility treatment subsidies and building a supportive, friendly environment for pregnancy and childrearing. Amendments to the Early Childhood Education and Care Act are also diversifying service models for childhood education and care, and expediting the addition of slots at public preschools and child care facilities.
>
> Since July 2018, the government has promoted an array of measures to counter declining birth rates such as increasing affordable education and care service capacities, reducing tuition costs, granting childrearing allowances, and raising salaries for child care and education personnel. Through all these measures, the government is throwing its full support behind childrearing households, giving young people the confidence to marry and start a family.

https://conventuslaw.com/report/taiwan-the-ministry-of-labor-amends-regulations/

Taiwan has pretty much changed its policies to counter low birth rate.

Subsidy example:

https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/taiwan/archives/2022/10/28/2003787868

Comment: Can you provide examples of where Taiwan has explicitly lowered regulations?

Comment: This would be a good answer on a question, which we've had before, about reversing declining birth rates.  Child care **is** part of possible government interventions.  However, this question specifically asks about *lowering childcare regulations* to get more childcare and this answer doesn't go anywhere near that subject.